# Stripe Payment: Java jsp ajax: Invalid Request: No such token

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, stripe-payments

The exception below is being thrown

> Invalid Request:  No such token

My code

```
 final Map<String, Object> chargeParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
      chargeParams.put("amount", 200);
      chargeParams.put("currency", "usd");
      chargeParams.put("card", cardParams);
      System.out.println(Token.retrieve(stripeToken));
      chargeParams.put("source",Token.retrieve(stripeToken));
      charge = Charge.create(chargeParams);
```

Please note--

1. I'm passing the token id from form field via ajax and the `token-id` matches with the one here in code.
2. I have valid `test-public` and `test-private` key from stripe account pasted in ajax and java code respectively.

Comment: it looks insanely weird to be setting both card and source. You should only be setting source and you should set it to the id of the token not the token object

Comment: Thanks for the response. It worked!